# Different ways to poll and process pending records in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, message-queue, polling

I have multiple listeners which poll a single table and search for pending records and processes (make api calls, run some business logic) them

1. a listener picks 5 pending records with limit query from the table and puts its listener_id in the column such that those records are locked for this particular listener
2. other listeners read for remaining pending records and lock 5 of them
3. once processed the listener would update the record status as done

this is done for horizontal scalability. A problem with this approach is, if the listener processes the records successfully but fails to update the record then the records gets stuck in progress state.

i thought of having TTL on theses locks, problem with this approach is that i cannot allow duplicate processing of these records.

i cant use select for update as its a blocking call.

please advice, what are the other ways of solving this

Answer (score 0):

I have listeners running within the application. So I decided to solve it this way.

1. Application creates records in the mysql table with the application_id (something which is unique per machine)
2. Listeners polls the table only by this application_id and an offset. Thus we achieve horizontal scalability and load balancing.
3. Listener is also recording the offset that what was the last record read. if the counter is 5 then in the next poll we search for records > 5. So this helps me in deduping as well.
4. Once the records are processed then we run a delete query on the table by application_id and records which are less than 5.